# What is a good product for installing a Windows service on 15 to 30 machines quickly?

Tags: service, installation, windows-installer, installshield, redgate

We have a Windows service which I'd like to run from a lot of machines. Right now we login and install the service manually on each machine when we need to update the services. This is a very time consuming process. Is there a tool which makes this easy to do?

Also, sometimes when we install upgrades we need to change the config files. Are there any tools that also support changing config files easily as part of the workflow? We were looking at RedGate's Deployment Manager but it only supports editing "appSettings" and "connectionStrings" elements and not other stuff in the config files.

Comment: This post is probably off-topic for SO (`Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic`), but - have you used Microsoft SCCM before?

Comment: It's 50% off topic.  Setup development is development.  The rest is enterprise engineering which is a Server Fault area.

Comment: This is one of the top requests on [UserVoice](http://redgate.uservoice.com/forums/176290-deployment-manager/suggestions/3578134-allow-variables-to-control-all-sections-in-config-) for Red Gate Deployment Manager.  Can add comments and votes there to help get it prioritised

Answer (score 0):

First you want to make a clean, well behaving MSI.  Windows Installer XML and IsWiX has a great story for that.

Once you have an MSI, you want to install it silently on your 15 machines.  There are many tools for this.  SCCM is a huge investment and a lot of infrastructure.  You might be able to just sling a .BAT file to do it.

robocopy /mir C:\package \machine1\c$\package
robocopy /mir C:\package \machine2\c$\package
...

psexec remote command on machine  msiexec /I foo.msi /qn REBOOT=R /l*v c:\package\install.log